# What is the number of solutions for $|\frac{4}{|x|}-2|=m$ for an $m\in \Bbb{R}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For:

- $m=0$ we've got two solutions; these are the x-intercepts,
- $m>2$ we've got two solutions,
- $m<0$ we've got no solutions.

However, how many solutions are there for $m=2$?

If there were $4$ solutions for $m=2$, then $f(x)$ would intersect the horizontal asymptote.

Comment: seems like two also: $x=\pm1$

Comment: Hint: sketch graph of the function $f(x)= |\frac{4}{|x|}-2|$ step by step and check how many points exists at the hight $y=m$.

Comment: @harvey if $m>2$ then $\frac{4}{|x|}-2=m$, it cannot equal $-m$, so there  are two solutions

Comment: @harvey: No, because $\frac4{|x|}$ is always positive.

Comment: This is a typical question for DESMOS. It shows you the graph and you don't need to go into heavy algebra, unless you want to go rigor, which from reading the OP's post, isn't expected. It also shows you that for $0<m<2$ there are 4 solutions

Comment: @imranfat I am using desmos, however 1) where does it show it? 2) now I am at it I want to know the heavy algebra part.

Comment: My smart ass answer will be 0 solutions because no single x can be such that $|4/|x| -2$ equals *all* real numbers.  It can only equal one. You should rewrite the questions how many solutions does $|4/|x| - 2| =m$ have for *an* m in R.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann oops. for $0 < M < 2$.... >_<

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately when I copy past from desmos, it doesn't copy the entry of the function, so I can't show mine. Moreover, my screen is acting up. However, going for the Algebra, I would read Brian's post, that makes lots of sense.

Comment: @harvey so, for $m=1$, I guess) Yes, there are 4 solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\left|\frac4{|x|}-2\right|=2$, then clearly $\frac4{|x|}$ must be $0$ or $4$. It can’t be $0$, so it must be $4$, and $|x|$ must be $1$. Thus, there are two solutions, $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is satisfied if

$$\frac{4}{|x|}-2=m\qquad \text{ or }\qquad 2-\frac{4}{|x|}=m$$

If $m=2$, these become

$$\frac{4}{|x|}=4\qquad \text{ or }\qquad -\frac{4}{|x|}=0$$

so $|x|=1$, i.e. $x=-1$ or $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You say correctly that there is no solution for $m<0$.

Assume $m\ge0$ and set $t=4/|x|$, so the equation becomes
$$
|t-2|=m
$$
with the condition $t>0$. Since $m\ge0$, we can square and get an equivalent equation:
$$
t^2-4t+4-m^2=0
$$
Now use the “rule of signs”. If $4-m^2<0$, that is, $m>2$, the equation has one positive root and one negative root. The negative root is discarded, the positive one gives two solutions for $x$.

For $0<m<2$ the equation has two positive roots (the discriminant is positive), that produce four solutions in $x$.

It remains to consider the cases $m=0$ and $m=2$.

If $m=0$, we get $t=2$ and so $x=\pm2$.

If $m=2$, the equation is $t^2-4t=0$; since $t>0$, we obtain $t=4$ and so $x=\pm1$.